# ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit scope

Tags: c#, servicepoint

Does changing ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit affect only the current process or the whole .NET platform. Please provide source.

Comment: Please contact your assigned Microsoft representative for source code.  Or use Reflector, available at a nominal fee to anybody, including you.

Comment: @Hans, or use dotPeek, which is free. And I think this isn't something that should require exploring .Net's source code. It should be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I actually meant the source of the information, not actual software source, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Setting properties of `ServicePointManager` pretty much does just that – it sets some static properties. (The actual code is more complicated than that, but I think that doesn't matter here.)

Those properties are used when creating new `ServicePoint` objects.

What follows from this is that their effect is as wide as for any other static property – that is one AppDomain.

While one process can have more than one AppDomain, most of the time, you deal only with one AppDomain per process. So, most of the time, setting the property affects the whole process. Sometimes not even that. It certainly doesn't affect other processes.